# How can I rotate a list right and left?

Tags: python, list, function

I have been trying to rotate a list left and right in python

```
def rotate(l, r):
    return l[r:] + l[:r]

l = eval(input())
r = int(input())

print(rotate(l, r))
```

but if i give input list as `['A','B','C','D',1,2,3,4,5]` and `r = -34` I'm getting output as

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but actual output is this :

```
['C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B']
```

Can anyone tell how can I do it?

Comment: what `r = -34 ` means as an information for rotation?

Comment: maybe see `l[-34:]` and `l[:-34]`. If you have value bigger then `len(l)` then you may get different result then you expect and you may need to get `modulo` of this value.

Comment: What happens is r=1 or r=-1

Comment: Note that `deque` is more suitable for rotating its content than a plain `list`.

Comment: for bigger values it would need rather `for`-loop with `[1:]`, `[:1]` or `[-1:]`, `[:-1]`

Comment: No, for bigger values you just need `r = r % len(l)`.

Comment: Please don't use eval

Comment: @TimRoberts `%` is simpler version but `for`-loop is other method which can more readable for beginner

Comment: Please, when you make a question like this, **don't make it take inputs from the user**, it is not related to the question at all.

Comment: @furas It's more than simpler, it has substantially better performance.

Comment: @TimRoberts that is right

Comment: r is the number of rotations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you could use `print()` and test it for different values

```
def rotate(l, r):
    return l[r:] + l[:r]

l = ['A','B','C','D',1,2,3,4,5]

print('len(l):', len(l))

for r in range(0, -34, -1):
    print(f"{r:3}", rotate(l, r))
```

And you see

```
len(l): 9
  0 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 -1 [5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4]
 -2 [4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3]
 -3 [3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2]
 -4 [2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1]
 -5 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
 -6 ['D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C']
 -7 ['C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B']
 -8 ['B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A']
 -9 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-10 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-11 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-12 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-13 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-14 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-15 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-16 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-17 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-18 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-19 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-20 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-21 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-22 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-23 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-24 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-25 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-26 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-27 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-28 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-29 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-30 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-31 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-32 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-33 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When `-r` is bigger then `len(r)` then it doesn't work as you would expect.
It gets `empty list` + `full list` or `full list` + `empty list`

The same problem is with `+34` and `-34`.

Because you get the same list for `r=len(l)`, `r=len(l)*2`, ...`r=len(l)*n` so you would use `modulo` (`r % len(l)`) to have value smaller then `len(l)` and get what you need.

```
def rotate(l, r):
    r = r % len(l)
    return l[r:] + l[:r]

l = ['A','B','C','D',1,2,3,4,5]

print('len(l):', len(l))

for r in range(0, -34, -1):
    print(f"{r:3}", rotate(l, r))
```

Result:

```
len(l): 9
  0 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 -1 [5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4]
 -2 [4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3]
 -3 [3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2]
 -4 [2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1]
 -5 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
 -6 ['D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C']
 -7 ['C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B']
 -8 ['B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A']
 -9 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-10 [5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4]
-11 [4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3]
-12 [3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2]
-13 [2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1]
-14 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
-15 ['D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C']
-16 ['C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B']
-17 ['B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A']
-18 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-19 [5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4]
-20 [4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3]
-21 [3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2]
-22 [2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1]
-23 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
-24 ['D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C']
-25 ['C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B']
-26 ['B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A']
-27 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-28 [5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4]
-29 [4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3]
-30 [3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2]
-31 [2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1]
-32 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
-33 ['D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

---

**BTW:**

Without `modulo` you would have to use `for`-loops with `[1:]`, `[:1]` or `[-1:]`,`[:-1]` - but it need many moves - so it may need more time and memory (but for small list it is not visible).

```
def rotate(l, r):
    if r >= 0:
        for _ in range(0, r, 1):
            l = l[1:] + l[:1]
    else:
        for _ in range(0, r, -1):
            l = l[-1:] + l[:-1]
        
    return l

l = ['A','B','C','D',1,2,3,4,5]

print('len(l):', len(l))

#for r in range(0, -34, -1):
#    print(f"{r:3}", rotate(l, r))
    
for r in range(0, 34, 1):
    print(f"{r:3}", rotate(l, r))
```

The same with one  `for`-loop

```
def rotate(l, r):

    if r >= 0:
        s = 1
    else:
        s = -1
        
    for _ in range(0, r, s):
        l = l[s:] + l[:s]
        
    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

If `r` can be bigger than the list you need to add the modulo operater as @tim-roberts mentioned:

```
def rotate(l, r):
     r = r % len(l)
     return l[r:] + l[:r]
```

Outputs

```
l = [1,2,3]

print(rotate(l,0))
[1, 2, 3]

print(rotate(l,1))
[2, 3, 1]

print(rotate(l,-1))
[3, 1, 2]

print(rotate(l,4))
[2, 3, 1]

print(rotate(l,-4))
[3, 1, 2]
```

(personally I'd also turn around the rotation direction, using e.g. `-r`)

Comment: "(personally I'd also turn around the rotation direction, using e.g. -r)" huh? Where exactly?

Comment: Its just personal gusto. For me positive int rotates "forward" (index in the list increased but for the last item). Using `-r` instead of `r` in the return line could do this.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, you want to change what direction of rotation the sign of `r` corresponds to